# Detecting when a long request has ended in NodeJS / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

I'm currently dealing with Server-sent events, where my pseudo-code looks like this:

```
var listeners = [];
app.get('/stream', function (req, res) {
    listeners.push({ req: req, res: res });
});

// ... something happens
notify(listeners);
```

Now this works quite fine acutally, but how do I know when a client closes the browser window so I don't run out of memory eventually? Do I have to manage this client-side or is there some `req.on('close', fn);` that I just can't find?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using something like the request's [`close` event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_2) should work just fine:

```
var listeners = [];

app.get('/stream', function (req, res) {
  var listener = { req: req, res: res };
  listeners.push(listener);
  req.on('close', function() {
    listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(listener), 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: got a query surrounding this approach, me too dealing with SSE's and i got a req.on('close') which works fine but if i have my streaming end point behind a web server relay then the req.on('close') is not getting fired? whereas with the actual end point it works just fine. Any idea about how to fire req.on('close')  when an end point is served behind a relay

Comment: @Sai if you're behind a relay and working with SSEs you should set a timeout on the request(`req.setTimeout(milliseconds)`) so that it will close after a set amount of time of inactivity